# Deleting list item in loop

Tags: python, list, loops, pygame

I'm currently trying to develop a game using pygame and I'm having some problems with some of my lists. Quite simple really, I want the shot to be deleted when going outside of the screen. My current code works perfect till I shoot more than one.

Current code:

```
#ManageShots
for i in range (len(ShotArray)):
    ShotArray[i].x += 10
    windowSurface.blit(ShotImage, ShotArray[i])
    if(ShotArray[i].x > WINDOWWIDTH):
        ShotArray.pop(i)
```

Error message:

```
ShotArray[i].x += 10
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Popping an item from the list moves everything *after* that item up one place. Thus, you end up with an index `i` that is easily outside of the range.

Remove items from your list after the loop, or loop over the list in reverse:

```
for shot in reversed(ShotArray):
    shot.x += 10
    windowSurface.blit(ShotImage, shot)
    if shot.x > WINDOWWIDTH:
        ShotArray.remove(shot)
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `len(SortArray)` is evaluated once, at the start of the loop. However, you then change the length of the list by calling `ShotArray.pop(i)`.

```
i = 0
while i < len(ShotArray):
    ShotArray[i].x += 10
    windowSurface.blit(ShotImage, ShotArray[i])
    if(ShotArray[i].x > WINDOWWIDTH):
        ShotArray.pop(i)
    else:
        i += 1
```

Comment: Yea, I was thinking the same thing, I did however think I would be able to make it work using some other remove option (like pop) The code I'm using is ActionScript you see, and there they do pretty much like I was trying here. You gave me some good insight tho, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

You probably want something like this:

```
# update stuff
for shot in ShotArray:
    shot.x += 10
    windowSurface.blit(ShotImage, shot)

# replace the ShotArray with a list of visible shots
ShotArray[:] =  [shot for shot in ShotArray if shot.x < WINDOWWIDTH]
```

Don't change the length of a list you're iterating over, it leads to chaos.

Comment: Any reason not to do `ShotArray =  [shot for shot in ShotArray if shot.x < WINDOWWIDTH]`?

Comment: By far the most complex anwser I got, appricate the help tho!